# Perl - transforming one data structure into another

Tags: perl, data-structures

I'm trying to convert one data structure into another, using Perl.

```
my $agent_details = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
    "SELECT agent_id, year, type FROM agents ORDER BY agent_id",
    { Slice => {} }
);
```

I end up with the data structure:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'agent_id' => '1',
            'year' => '2000',
            'type' => '14',
          },
          {
            'agent_id' => '2',
            'year' => '2001',
            'type' => '14',
          },
          {
            'agent_id' => '3',
            'year' => '2002',
            'type' => '14',
          },
          {
            'agent_id' => '4',
            'year' => '2000',
            'type' => '14',
          },
          {
            'agent_id' => '5',
            'year' => '2001',
            'type' => '14',
          },
          {
            'agent_id' => '6',
            'year' => '2002',
            'type' => '14',
          },
]
```

What I would like to do is transform into a hash of arrays:

```
$VAR2 = {
          '2000' => [1, 4],
          '2001' => [2, 5],
          '2002' => [3, 6],
}
```

I was able to accomplish this with some ugly loops, but I feel like there is an easier / better cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Why do you select type if you discard it later? Also, why selectall when you want to make your own structure?

Comment: @TLP - I don't need to select type, so that was removed in my actual code. Can you suggest a better way to get the database rows into the structure I want without using selectall_arrayref?

Comment: TLP was suggesting that you remove the useless `, type`, and that you read each row one at a time. The former makes sense (if you don't use `$agent_details` for anything else), but the second one is debatable.

Comment: @ikegami Its a simpler solution to loop over all the results and store them in a structure. Something like `while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) { push @{ $hash{$row->{year} }, $row->{agent_id}; }`

Comment: @TLP, It's virtually identical. And possibly slower.

Comment: @TLP, you store the data in a temporary variables in your code too. You just call it `$row` instead of `$agent_details`. Use the one you like, but don't make stuff up to justify it. Well, don't share it.

Comment: @ikegami I haven't made any stuff up. The `$row` variable goes out of scope after the loop. `$agent_details` is global and will remain throughout the program. No need to be rude.

Comment: @TLP, First you complain that it is temporary. So now you're complaining that it's NOT temporary. Seriously! Just add curlies if you want to be more limited.  /// Re "*I haven't made any stuff up*", You said a virtually identical solution is simpler. Twice. You said a solution that uses a temp var doesn't use a temp var.

Comment: @ikegami You're focusing on the wrong part. I said "useless temp variable", meaning a useless variable, that stays in memory. My version also uses a temp variable, but mine is gone after it passes out of scope. And yes, I think my version is simpler, from the point of view that creating a complex data structure, then decoding and simplifying that structure, is more complicated than just creating the structure you want from the start. Also, I see you got a downvote on your answer, and that is not mine, in case you are wondering. This debate is pointless, just arguing about semantics.

Comment: @TLP, Re "*I said "useless temp variable",  meaning a useless variable, that stays in memory.*", Well, you got the definition of variable correct, but temp means the very opposite of long-lasting, and it's you also got the definition of useless wrong.

Comment: @TLP, "*creating a complex data structure*", An array of rows is not a more complex data structure than an iterator of rows. They're both a trivially simple list of rows. (If anything, I'd consider a iterator more complex since it's far less familiar to beginners.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my %agents_by_year;
for $agent ( @$agents ) {
   push @{ $agents_by_year{ $agent->{ year } } }, $agent->{ agent_id };
}
```

Comment: This seems to be creating a reference to an array. For example:
print $agents_by_year{2000} gives me ARRAY(0x25f4858) instead of the expected "14".

Comment: Re "*This seems to be creating a reference to an array. *", It does, as requested. /// Re "* instead of the expected "14".*", You didn't ask for `"14"`, you asked for `[1,4]`. You'll find that `print(Dumper(\%agents_by_year))` matches your requested output exactly. (Except for whitespace, and the order of the hash elements which can't be controlled.) Correct your question if it's wrong. Then leave a comment here to let me know, and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do. For example, say I had another selectall_arrayref on the 'properties' table with two fields (one being year). I now want to use the property's year  to access my array, and find the minimum value from all elements. The code I'm trying is: for my $property (@$properties) { my $min_array_value = min $agents_by_year{ $property->{year} }; which doesn't work. In addition, I want to delete that array element after I use it, to which I tried: $agents_by_year{ $property->{year} } = grep !/$min_array_value/, $agents_by_year{ $property->{year} }; Thanks for your help

Comment: If `min` takes a list of scalars (like the `min` from List::Util), then you want `min @{ $agents_by_year{ $property->{year} } }`. Same idea for your `grep`

Comment: thanks, that seems to work properly. However, the syntax seems... unnecessary with the array reference. How can I create just a simple array for each hash value - or, is the way we're doing it now the correct way? Edit: if a non-referenced array + cleaner syntax is possible, I can edit my question to specify that. At any rate, it appears your answer was correct - so thank you.

Comment: @ComputersAreNeat You cannot store an array in a hash value, you can only store a reference to an array. But it is the same thing.

Comment: Hash values are necessarily scalars. They can't be arrays.

Comment: Thanks @TLP. So it sounds like there is no way to clean up the @{ $agents_by_year{ $property->{year} } } syntax if I want to store arrays as a hash value.

Comment: There's `$agents_by_year{ $property->{year} }->@*` if you prefer that

Comment: You could also use meaningful names. `my $year = $property->{ year }; my $agents = $agents_by_year{ $year }; @$agents` (or `$agents->@*`)

Comment: @ComputersAreNeat I think you are just getting confused by syntax. You are storing it in an array, but the hash value is the reference to that array, not the array itself. Think of it as `my @array = qw(foo bar); my %hash; $hash{"key"} = \@array`